# httpSession in Grails

Tags: grails, httpsession

I need to access the domain class User of the current session. The following code works:

```
class RatingController {    
def rate = {
    def rating = params.rating
    def artist = Artist.get( params.id )
    def user = User.get(1)
    user.addToRatings(new Rating(artist:artist, rating:rating))
    user.save()
    render(template: "/artist/rate", model: [artist: artist, rating: rating])
}
}
```

But instead of explicitly get the user with ID equal 1 (User.get(1)) I need to access the user of the current session. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
class RatingController {    
def rate = {
    def rating = params.rating
    def artist = Artist.get( params.id )
    def user = user.session
    user.addToRatings(new Rating(artist:artist, rating:rating))
    user.save()
    render(template: "/artist/rate", model: [artist: artist, rating: rating])
}
}
```

I'm still struggling to fully understand the httpSession concept, so a little help would be great.
Thank in advance.

**UPDATE**

In my UserController, my authentication looks like this:

```
def authenticate = {
  def user = User.findByLoginAndPassword(params.login, params.password)
  if(user){
    session.user = user
    flash.message = "Hello ${user.name}!"
    redirect(controller:"event", action:"list")
  }else{
    flash.message = "Sorry, ${params.login}. Please try again."
    redirect(action:"create")
  }
}
```

Comment: are you putting the user on the session?  are you using some authentication mechanism that will provide it?

Comment: based on your edits, manipulate the session as I described in my answer.  You need  a string key.  Do `session['SESSION_USER'] = user` and then `session['SESSION_USER']`.  You probably want to define the string SESSION_USER as a constant in your application.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it throws the exception: "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session".

Comment: then test before you set it.  `if (session['userkey'] != null) {//set}`

Comment: when you put objects on your session, you need to make them implement Serializable. When you reference a domain object, taken from a session, they are not attached to the Hibernate session, and you need to re-attach them, before you can save them again. This is done by: user.attach()

Answer (score 3):

the http session is nothing more than data that is maintained among a sequence of requests from a single source, like a browser.

To put something on the session, just do

`session.setAttribute("key", value)`

and to get data off the session just do

`session.getAttribute("key")`

Grails also adds some fanciness to session access as outlined [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html).  Their example shows

```
def user = session["user"]
session["user"] = "John"
asset "John" == session.user
```

Note that if you are using a grails plugin for authentication and authorization, it will probably provide a way to get the user.  For example Spring Security gives you the following

`springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()`

depending on the details of your plugin, that user might or might not be on the session.

Answer (score 2):

In your code I noticed you wrote

```
def user = user.session
```

When I think you mean

```
def user = session.user
```

The other thing I do is make it session.userId ie `session.userId = user.id` and then

```
def user = User.get(session.userId)
```

Not sure if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use .merge():

```
user.merge(flush: true)
```

This is because the instance is detached from the persistence context when you save it to HttpSession. Here is the doc from grails:
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html

Comment: Plus one for merge(). This attaches the User object back to the existing hibernate session.